# node-sass-middleware is not installing on windows

Tags: express, sass, node-modules, node-sass, css-frameworks

**node-sass-middleware** is not installing in my computer. I've tried almost every method to do so but nothing get hand.

It was saying to install latest version of python (I do), latest version of VS Code (I do) even after error is coming.

I've tried its alternative module **node-sass** but it does not match my need.

I want to setup **this**

```
const sassMiddleware = require('node-sass-middleware');
|
|
|
app.use(
     sassMiddleware({
        src: __dirname,
        dest: __dirname,
        debug: true,
        outputStyle: 'extended',
        prefix: '/css'
     })
);
```

I've tried to install **node-sass-middleware** but its giving me this error :

[see the error here from my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiBzq.jpg)

[continue error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Q7Ms.jpg)

Comment: The error is related to missing Visual Studio, not VS Code. Also, the error comes from node-gyp trying to build/compile some binaries for node-sass which is a dependency of node-sass-middleware. Btw, node-sass is deprecated so I would suggest to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass with Webpack or similar package bundler.

Answer (score 0):

I found one way to use node-sass-middleware

Step1) download library from https://github.com/sass/node-sass-middleware

step2) extract it(if you download zip file) and now create an `node-sass-middleware` folder in `node_module folder` of your project

step3) copy `all folders and files` from an zip file(extract) and `paste` it inside  `node-sass-middleware` folder(that we created in node_module FOLDER)

step4) now run your code in vs code for sass

Answer (score 0):

Use that command to give root previlige to npm to make necessary changes. Hopefully this will resolve your issue.

```
npm install node-sass --unsafe-perm
```